# Recover Debian 10 from lost `/home`

Tags: linux, recovery

My HDD decided to die on me while working. On assessment, it's hardware failure. I've 2 drives, the SSD contains all the `/` and OS installations. While, the HDD contains all `/home` and other partitions. Windows works, but its other drive doesn't show. Debian & Mint don't boot waiting for response from the `/home` partition on the HDD.

OSes: Windows 10, Debian 10, Mint 19

I've attached a new SSD in place of the dead HDD. What is the best way to restore my system to use my existing Debian installation.

Lessons learnt:

- Change your storage device every 30 Months.
- Keep `/home` & `/` partitions on the same drive.

I've looked and looked, but there is no such instance I've found on the internet. I don't just want to reinstall a system. I want to know how to get my old system. I don't have much hopes, but if there's anywhere I can find an answer to this, it's here.

Comment: Your lessons learnt are bad ones.  No need to change storage device every 30 months.  You will get greater reliability, performance and lower overall cost by using RAID1 - drives should last significantly more then 30 months, with many guaranteeed for 5 years.  Home SHOULD be kept on a different partition to / to make resizing easier.  If in doubt (under Linux) use LVM to give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure on your distro, but it would seem likely that the drive is waiting for /home to become available before finalising the boot.  If this is the case, it is just a matter of editing /etc/fstab and commenting out the line for mounting /home.

You should be able to do this by using a boot disk, or by booting a minimum environment by adding "init=/bin/bash" to the grub boot (for a single boot) to give you a raw bash shell as root without going through the normal full initialization process.

Once you have got the system booting, you can go through the process of initialising (partitioning and formatting in the simplest case) your SSD and then modifying /etc/fstab to mount it as /home

Comment: I have a live usb and can edit `fstab`, but what i don't understand is all the directories and config files that are integral part of a `/home` partition. I don't have those files/dirs. Will Debian recreate them? Without them will my system be broken? Or is this irrelevant?

Comment: I don't know if Debian will recreate them - it will likely recreate some provided the users home directory exists.  Your system may, to some degree be broken - but to what extent depends on what your users are doing and what is stored there.  I expect "history" files will be recreated, but files like .profile and .bashrc won't be recreated.  (the system ones will be used instead - things wont die or error because the files are missing).